# Android frames per second

Tags: android, frame-rate

Is it possible to get these values programmatically:

- frames per second
- how often the method `onDraw()` is called if the whole View is invalidated immediately.

Answer (score 4):

1) Here is how I'm counting fps:

```
public class MyView extends View {
    private int    mFPS = 0;         // the value to show
    private int    mFPSCounter = 0;  // the value to count
    private long   mFPSTime = 0;     // last update time

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - mFPSTime > 1000) {
            mFPSTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            mFPS = mFPSCounter;
            mFPSCounter = 0;
        } else {
            mFPSCounter++;
        }

        String s = "FPS: " + mFPS;
        canvas.drawText(s, x, y, paint);

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

or just write your own object that would calculate this for you :)...

2) Try using

```
Log.d(tag, "onDraw() is called");
```

in your onDraw() method.